# ng-tags-input autocompete not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I want to use the `ng-tags-input` with Autocomplete functionality, but I'm getting an error:

> e.then is not a function

This is my HTML

```
<tags-input ng-model="selectedBodyParts" class="ui-tags-input" add-on-paste="true">
      <auto-complete source="loadBodyParts($query)" min-length="0" load-on-focus="true">

      </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

And AngularJS Code:

```
    $scope.loadBodyParts = function ($query){
        var bodypartList = angular.copy($scope.bodyParts);
        return bodypartList.filter(function(bodypart) {
            return bodypart.bodyPartName.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
};
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if you could provide a plunker showing your problem? You can use [this template](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:93P2qxOjYmlcYSqDmo39).

Answer (score 0):

The function you use with `ng-tag-input` to load your sources should return a `Promise` object, a Promise has a function with the signature `.then(fn, fn)` which is probably what it's looked for and didn't find, hence your..

`e.then is not a function` error

If you'll go to the [demos section](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos), under "Simple tags input with autocomplete", you will see this code

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    return $http.get('tags.json');
};
```

In angular `$http.get` returns a promise. If i'll have to change your code, I'd probably use `$q` to promisify your data and return a promise that hold your filtered data.

```
$scope.loadBodyParts = function ($query){
    var bodypartList = angular.copy($scope.bodyParts);
    var promisifyMe = bodypartList.filter(function(bodypart) {
        return bodypart.bodyPartName.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    return $q.when(promisifyMe);
};
```

[$q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)